# group news by year in frontend (TYPO3, news system)

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 9, News Plugin (News system).

I am looking for a way to group news articles by year, like this:

```
2019
--------
article 1
article 2
article 3
--------
2018
--------
article 1
article 2
...
```

I can't find an easy solution for this and find it hard to believe that the only way to implement this is to edit TYPO3's source code...

Can anyone help?

-------------------------- Edit

Fixed and working code suggested by Bernd Wilke:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:n="http://typo3.org/ns/GeorgRinger/News/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
    =====================
        Templates/News/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
    <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
    <f:if condition="{news}">
        <f:then>
            <f:variable name="oldYear">2010</f:variable>
            <f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
                <f:variable name="currentYear"><f:format.date format="%Y">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date></f:variable>
                <f:if condition="{oldYear} < {currentYear}">
                    <hr />
                    <h3>{currentYear}</h3>
                    <hr />
                </f:if>
                <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
            </f:for>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <div class="alert ">
                <f:translate key="list_nonewsfound" />
            </div>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
    <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
</f:section>
</html>
```

However, I award this question to Georg Ringer as his solution was working right away.

Comment: if you you have set your installation to debug mode (InstallTool -> Settings -> Configuration Presets), you additionally can set `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0`

Comment: if you want a headline for the current year as for any other year you need to initialize `oldYear` with another value than from the first record. The headline is only triggered if `currentYear` is different than `oldYear`

Comment: Hello,sorry but I can't get it to work, I receive an error. I updated my post with the corrected code I use.

Comment: are you sure that you are in debug-mode ( **settings-> configuration presets -> debug settings** ) and that `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0`will not be overwritten ?

Comment: Hello Bernd, I appologize for late response, I was absent and couldn't respond. The variable setter was wrong, I changed it to <f:variable name... (means, I removed the ".set"). Now I do receive an output. I get a list with the news teasers, but the headline is not displayed correctly. It appears only once and is not rendered, it outputs: "{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date("Y")}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is possible by fluid by using the ViewHelper `f:groupedFor`, see [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ViewHelperReference/latest/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/GroupedFor.html).

There is also an example in the [docs of the news extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Tutorials/Templates/GroupNewsRecords/Index.html?highlight=group). So the example should work like that

```
<f:groupedFor each="{news}" as="groupedNews" groupBy="yearOfDatetime" groupKey="year">
        <div style="border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;margin:10px;">
                <h1>{year}</h1>
                <f:for each="{groupedNews}" as="newsItem">
                        <div style="border:1px solid pink;padding:5px;margin:5px;">
                                {newsItem.title}
                        </div>
                </f:for>
        </div>
</f:groupedFor>
```

however I also want to warn about the following

> **Keep an eye on performance!**
>
> To be able to group the records, fluid
>   will load every record itself and groups those afterwards. If you plan
>   to group many records just for getting something like a count, maybe
>   it is better to fire the query directly and don’t use fluid for that.
>
> *However if the result is on a cacheable page, the issue is only relevant on the first hit.*

Comment: Hello Georg (und herzliche Grüsse aus Zürich/Schweiz). Thank you for pointing me to "f:groupedFor". Your code worked right away for me.

Comment: one question though: I can't find anything about "yearOfDateTime". Where does it come from? Is there a list of all parameters I can use with groupBy=? And what function does "groupKey" have?

Comment: `groupKey` is the name of the variable which is used to group. And you can use any property (which basically means getters) of the object you want to group by. in this case it is https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Model/News.php#L356-L359

Answer (score 1):

There is no typoscript option for grouping like this.

But you can do it in FLUID:
Copy the template files for news listing to your (site) extension and modify it according to your needs: build in a group processing.

```
<f:variable.set name="oldYear">0000</f:variabel.set>
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
    <f:variable.set name="currentYear">{newsItem.datetime->f:format.date("Y")}</f:varaible.set>
    <f:if condition="{oldYear} == {currentYear}">
        <hr />
        <h3>{currentYear}</h3>
        <hr />
        <f:variable.set name="oldYear">{currentYear}</f:variable.set>
    </f:if>
    <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
</f:for>
```

---

You might use one of the viewhelpers mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870481/display-list-of-elements-grouped-by-year-and-by-month-in-typo3-fluid) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383772/how-to-display-news-articles-grouped-by-year-with-typo3-versatile-news-system).

Comment: Ext:News provides a Signal / Slot where you could modify new thews and add that grouping. That might be better then moving such logic to the View.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunaltey I can't get your code to work. I entered your code in file "C:\xampp3\htdocs\fileadmin\news\Resources\Private\Templates\Styles\Twb\Templates\News\List.html" but it genereates an error: "Meine News
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20190522073111b1b9b1b5 ". Please see my edited post for the updated List.html I used.

Comment: maybe it only is a small typo: try `newsItem.datetime` instead of `newsItem.date` (I remembered the field name wrong)

Comment: makes no difference unfortunately, still not working

Comment: Then you need to change your system to give clear messages and a stacktrace to identify your error.

Comment: Hello Bernd, finally I managed to make your code work. However, I had to change it. Please see the line with "newsItem.datetime->format...". And I had to remove this line from the logic otherwise only one year/headline was outputted: <f:variable name="oldYear">{currentYear}</f:variable>. I found your solution very Interesting and it seems to give me a good level of control. However, I will award this question to user Georg Ringer, as his solution worked right away. I hope that's ok for you?